# Managament of Stock After Order Success in Php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-update, stock

I Am Working On Inventory Store Project. Everything Goes Well But I am Facing an issue After the Success Of the Order.
When User Place an Order And Redirect To Checkout Page.When the user  Fill's Billing Form And Click On Button. I Run a Process to Store Order and Its Detail In the Database and a process to Manage Stock Of Product In the Database.

Values Coming From Hidden Fields:

```
         <?php
          foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {
         ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $value['product_id'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $value['product_name'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_color[]" value="<?php echo $value['product_color'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_size[]" value="<?php echo $value['product_size'] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_quantity[]" value="<?php echo $value['product_quantity'] ?>"> 
   
         <?php } ?>
```

Storing Values In Array:

```
           // ==========================================

            $pcolor = array();
            foreach ($_POST['product_color'] as $pc => $pcvalue) {
                $pcolor[] .=  $pcvalue;
            }
            $product_color = implode(', ', $pcolor);
            // ==========================================


            $psize = array();
            foreach ($_POST['product_size'] as $ps => $psvalue) {
                $psize[] .=  $psvalue;
            }
            $product_size = implode(', ', $psize);
            // ==========================================


            $pid = array();
            foreach ($_POST['product_id'] as $proid => $pidvalue) {
                $pid[] .=  $pidvalue;
            }
            $product_id = implode(', ', $pid);
            // ==========================================


            $pquantity = array();
            foreach ($_POST['product_quantity'] as $pq => $pqvalue) {
                $pquantity[] .=  $pqvalue;
            }
            $product_quantity = implode(', ', $pquantity);
            // ==========================================



            $pname = array();
            foreach ($_POST['product_name'] as $pn => $pnvalue) {
                $pname[] .=  $pnvalue;
            }
            $product_name = implode(', ', $pname);
            // ==========================================
```

My Code:

```
            // Update Query 
            $update_quantity = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])); $i++) {

                $select_quan = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE pid = {$pid[$i]}";
                $result_quan = mysqli_query($con, $select_quan);                    

                while ($row_quan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_quan)) {

                    $quantity_after_order[$i] =   $row_quan['pquantity'] - ($pquantity[$i]);

                    $update_quantity .= "UPDATE product SET pquantity = '$quantity_after_order[$i]' WHERE pid=$pid[$i]; ";

                }
                $res = mysqli_query($con,$update_quantity);
                print_r($res);
            }
            print_r($update_quantity);
```

$update_quantity query runs Perfect But mysqli_query Update only 1st Value and Second Product Value in Database Remain the Same.

Output of $res = mysqli_query($con,$update_quantity)

```
         1
```

Output of update_quantity

```
         UPDATE product SET pquantity = '211' WHERE pid=7; UPDATE product SET pquantity = '9' WHERE pid=31;
```

Plz Help Me What Should I Do To Update All Product Quantities(which user order) in the Database.

Comment: `$res = mysqli_query($con,$update_quantity)` should be inside the while loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Found The Solution:

I Was Using

> **mysqli_query**

I Updated mysqli_query To

> **mysqli_multi_query**

And My Code Run's Correct.

My Code:

I Remove mysqli_query From while Loop:

```
            $res = "";
            $update_quantity = "";
            for ($i = 0; $i < (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])); $i++) {

                $select_quan = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE pid = {$pid[$i]}";
                $result_quan = mysqli_query($con, $select_quan);

                while ($row_quan = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_quan)) {

                    $quantity_after_order[$i] =   $row_quan['pquantity'] - ($pquantity[$i]);

                    $update_quantity .= "UPDATE product SET pquantity = '$quantity_after_order[$i]' WHERE pid=$pid[$i]; ";
                }
            }
```

And Add This Portion Of Code in my Project:

```
            // Execute multi query
            if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $update_quantity)) {
                do {
                    // Store first result set
                    if ($result = mysqli_store_result($con)) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
                        }
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    }
                    // if there are more result-sets, the print a divider
                    if (mysqli_more_results($con)) {
                    }
                    //Prepare next result set
                } while (mysqli_next_result($con));
            }
```

After These Updates:

Product Quantity Of Every Order Product Update.

Thanks